# file_write failing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io

I have a piece of code written in codeigniter that reads a csv file and is supposed to write to a JSON file which i can read from later. The problem is that if I set a path for the file, the code fails but it works if i don't save a filepath.

Here is my code

```
$csvfile = array('csvfile' => $this->upload->data($upload_field_name));             
            $csvdata = $this->csvreader->parse_file($csvfile['csvfile']['full_path']);  
            $data['jsondata'] = json_encode($csvdata);          
            $path = '../uploads/'.$current_user_name.'.json';   
            if ( ! write_file( $path, $data['jsondata'],'w+' )    ) 
            {
                    echo "File writing failed"; 
                    echo $path;
            }                                               
            else
             {
                $this->load->view('dashboard');
            }
```

I have looked for possible solutions but couldn't find any.

Comment: whats the error code please?

Comment: Does the uploads folder exist and is it writable? The path must be relative to index.php.

Comment: The upload folder exists and it is writable. I have to check up on the path being relative to the index.php. And there is no error code. Thanks for the answers. ill try and see what happens.